# What was the name of the object-oriented C language I used in the 1980s on the Mac

Tags: apple-macintosh, c

I clearly recall working with an object-oriented C derivative on the Mac but I cannot find any definitive references to it.

It was back in the days of System 7 and later System 8. It had both constructors and destructors and, I think, method overloading.

One of its elegant features was the ability to define an object which could be put on the stack (yes, the **object** was pushed, not its reference) which could capture a current state during construction (`getGWorld()` rings a bell) and could automatically revert the state to its original on destruction when the method returned. This ensured that all changes to the state were reverted automatically on method exit, kind of like a modern `finally` clause.

I think it was called `object-C` and I *think* it might have been a `Symantec` product.

Comment: `getGWorld` is from an API/SDK so could have been any language.  <strike>Could it have been "object pascal"? - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Pascal#Early_history_at_Apple </strike>

Comment: For the name, you were probably getting confused with "Objective C" which was for a later OS branded as Mac.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 and first popularised by NeXT!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like [THINK C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THINK_C), originally known as Lightspeed C and eventually acquired by Symantec. It included object-oriented extensions to C, with single inheritance added to `struct` in particular, and provided a class library wrapping the Macintosh UI. [This MacTech review](http://preserve.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.05/05.10/ThinkCTutor/index.html) gives a decent summary of the features (before THINK was extended to support C++ and became Symantec C++).

Many of the “nice” features of the object-oriented C model used here weren’t specific to THINK C and can be found in other systems using C; for example, `struct` instances can be declared on the stack, and can contain function pointers. Making them nice to *use* in practice does require extensions though.